# MPI: How to guarantee no two process from different communicator doing writing at the same time

Tags: c, mpi

I want to split the `MPI_comm_world` into smaller communicator, so I learned to use `MPI_Comm_split` from [this link](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/introduction-to-groups-and-communicators/)

I copy the code here, it shows how to split `MPI_comm_world` into 4 color

```
// Get the rank and size in the original communicator
int world_rank, world_size;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

int color = world_rank / 4; // Determine color based on row

// Split the communicator based on the color and use the
// original rank for ordering
MPI_Comm row_comm;
MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, color, world_rank, &row_comm);

int row_rank, row_size;
MPI_Comm_rank(row_comm, &row_rank);
MPI_Comm_size(row_comm, &row_size);

printf("WORLD RANK/SIZE: %d/%d \t ROW RANK/SIZE: %d/%d\n",
    world_rank, world_size, row_rank, row_size);

MPI_Comm_free(&row_comm);
```

Now if I distribute my tasks to different color communicator, and each task paralleled in its color domain. What is more each task has a file writing operation.

Typically, if there is only `MPI_comm_world`, we use `if(world_rank==0)` to guaranty only one process doing writing at the same time.

However, now we have different color, each color doing its own job and have to write its own result to file.

`if(color_rank==0)` is clearly not sufficient.

**So What is the best way to guaranty no two process from different communicator doing writing at the same time?**

Comment: Just write one file per color?

Comment: @Zulan if several process writing 4 file simultaneously, I think it will harm the performance, am I right?

Comment: That entirely depends on the file system and on the actual number of processes. It may be beneficial or decremental to performance. *Typically* for optimal performance you want to expose *some* parallelism to the file system, but not *1-file-per-rank*. If you really care about I/O performance, you should use a parallel I/O middleware/library that is tuned to your particular system. There are many available such as ADIOS, HDF5, IOFSL, MPI-IO, SION, just to name a few.